# AWS Lambda Dynamic DB Switching Singelton (Node)

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, singleton

I'm trying to take advantage of db connection reuse in Lambda, by keeping the code outside of the handler.

For example - something like:

```
import dbconnection from './connection'

const handler(event, context, callback){
    //use dbconnection 
}
```

The issue is I don't decide what database to connect to until I do a lookup to see where they should be connecting. In my specific case I have **'customer=foo'** in a query param then I can look to see that foo should connect to **database1**.

So what I need to do is something like this :

```
    const dbconnection = require('./connection)('database1')
```

The way it is now I need to do this in every handler method which is expensive.

Is there some way I can pull the query parameter, look up my database and set it / switch it globally within the Lambda execution context?

I've tried this:

```
import dbconnection from './connection'

const handler(event, context, callback){
    const client = dbconnection.setDatabase('database1') 
}

....
./connection.js

 setDatabase(database) {
      if(this.currentDatabase !== database) {
         // connect to different database
         this.currentDatabase = database; 
      }
 }
```

Everything works locally with `sls offline` but doesn't work through the AWS Lambda execution context. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You can either hardcode (or provide it via environment variable) it or not. If you can, then pull it out of then handler and it will not be executed each time. If you can't, as you have mentioned, then what you are trying to do is to make lambda stateful. Lambda was designed to be stateless and AWS intentionally doesn't expose specific informations about the underlying containers so that you don't start doing something like what you are trying to do now - introducing state to it.